# Formatting in mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, database, formatting

I am using PHP to execute a query to a database. I have been successful in executing many queries with the program but one recent one has given me trouble. The original SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT Champion, RunnerUp
FROM playoffs
WHERE Champion = "Detroit Red Wings"
AND (RunnerUp = "Montreal Canadiens" OR RunnerUp = "New York Rangers");
```

This runs successfully and produces the correct output when used in HeidiSQL directly on the database. I tried implementing it in the program as follows, swapping out the actual team names for PHP variables:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Champion, RunnerUp
                FROM playoffs
                WHERE Champion = '$champion'
                AND (RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp' OR RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp2')") ;
```

In this version, it seems that the embedded set of parenthesis is not being identified as such, instead appearing to be part of the quotation. This version produced no output.

I modified it as follows:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Champion, RunnerUp
                FROM playoffs
                WHERE Champion = '$champion'
                AND RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp' OR RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp2'") ;
```

Removing the second set of parenthesis, it executes but does not produce the desired result because the logic reads differently, giving me tuples for whenever $champion and $RunnerUp match or whenever $RunnerUp2 is the runner-up. Is there anyway to execute this statement as I originally intended using PHP?

UPDATE: After putting the query into a variable as follows:

```
 $query = "SELECT Champion, RunnerUp
                FROM playoffs
                WHERE Champion = '$champion'
                AND (RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp' OR RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp2')";
```

and echoing it, I got the output

```
SELECT Champion, RunnerUp FROM playoffs WHERE Champion = '' AND (RunnerUp = 'Montreal Canadiens' OR RunnerUp = 'Toronto St. Patricks')
```

So it looks like for some reason, my champion variable never receives anything. This is because when calling it originally, it was called as 'Champion' instead of 'champion.'

Comment: Put the query inside of a variable called `$query` then you can `echo $query;` and see if the query looks as you expect it to. There may be trailing whitespace on your `$champion`, `$RunnerUp`, or `$RunnerUp2` variables that you are missing. Then call like this: `mysqli_query($link, $query);` because it will look neater. Update the question if that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: That helped me figure out where I made a formatting error previous to these lines. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out where I went wrong previously, it appears that this code:

```
$query = "SELECT Champion, RunnerUp
            FROM playoffs
            WHERE Champion = '$champion'
            AND (RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp' OR RunnerUp = '$RunnerUp2')";
```

will in fact work. Though, as mentioned in the comments above, it would be cleaner to add the query to a variable and call it.

Comment: `print_r` is your friend when trying to debug code! :)